# How to check whether port is open in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

I do not have `telnet` command in my system.

However my system is installed with `Windows 10`, so there must be a way to check whether particular port is open or not in a remote system. That particular remote system is accessible I had checked with `ping` command.

So here is my simple question,- how to check whether particular port is open or not using `powershell`.

Command `netstat` could brief for local system service & port and particular protocol either UDP or TCP is up & runnning. As I do not have `telnet` I need this to be sorted out and tackled by `powershell`. Any advise and suggestion are welcome.

Comment: Test-NetConnection ?

Comment: Even I suspect that, but I have to be so sure about that. Or is Test-NetConnection is `powershell` `cmdlet`. I got error saying it is not either while I try that string patched in `powershell`

Comment: I just amazed present system which was in use is `Windows 7`, Thanks for your immediate attention. Much appreciated. Thanks for @david-martin attention & consideration rather not to be taken as what it should be, as its the way I'd interpreted. Thanks.

Comment: `Test-NetConnection localhost -p 8080`, in place of localhost you can try any host. Thanks for all, for getting to know about these `cmdlet`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Test-NetConnection ###.###.###.### -Port ##
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following to try and open a port, if no error is returned the port is open:

```
$ipaddress = ""
$port = ""
$tcpClient = new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient
$tcpClient.Connect("$ipaddress", $Port)
$tcpClient.Dispose()
```

Here's a more complete example, which returns true/false which is the way that [Test-Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path) works:

```
function Test-Port
{
    param
    (
        $Address,
        $Port
    )
    $tcpClient = new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient
    try
    {
        $tcpClient.Connect("$Address", $Port)
        $true
    }
    catch
    {
        $false
    }
    finally
    {
        $tcpClient.Dispose()
    }
}

Test-Port -Address localhost -Port 80
Test-Port -Address localhost -Port 81
```

Depending on the version of Powershell/Windows you are using [Test-NetConnection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn372891(v=wps.630).aspx) may be more appropriate.

Comment: You should dispose the object afterwards, though.

Comment: Thanks for give a clarity on how to check whether particular Service is up & running using `Powershell` in place of using legacy `Telnet` in command-line mode. And for Semantics on how to use Objects in `Powershell`.

Comment: Obviously on the other hosts which is in reach.